# Rails form used for new and edit - set todays date vs existing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that uses the same events/_form.erb for new and editing an event.

If it's a new event, I want to pre-select today's date.  If it's being edited, I want to have it show the already entered date.

I thought I could do this with a flash setting.

This is the events/new.html.erb:

```
<% flash[:newevent] = "true" %>
<%= render :partial => 'form' %>
```

This is the code in events/_form.html.erb

```
       <% if flash[:newevent] = "true" %>
         <%= f.input :starts_at, :as => :string, :label => 'Date', :input_html => {:class => 'datepicker', :value => Date.today.to_s} %>
       <% else %>
         <%= f.input :starts_at, :as => :string, :label => 'Date', :input_html => {:class => 'datepicker'} %>
       <% end %>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

controller:

```
@new_event = true # or false in edit
```

view:

```
<% if @new_event %>
```

or just this in in view:

```
<% if f.object.new_record? %>
```

Comment: The <% if f.object.new_record? %> worked!  Thanks - I'll accept in a few minutes (when it will let me).

Answer (score 1):

Is this you're looking for ?

```
... :value => f.object.starts_as || Date.today.to_s
```